# Table row shifts down when displaying validation message, not aligned

Tags: asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc, html

**MY JSFIDDLE To Replicate the Issue I'm having:**
http://jsfiddle.net/YLQdy/

**CSS**

```
.datagrid table { 
    border-collapse: collapse; 
    text-align: left; 
    width: 100%; 
} 

.datagrid .table-one {
    float: left;
    width:50%;
}

.datagrid .table-two {
    float: right;
    width:50%;
}
```

**My Table for Registration**

```
<div>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Registration</legend>

            <div class="datagrid">
                <!--LEFT SIDE -->
                <div>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(p => p.Email)</div>
                <table class="table-one">
                        <tr>
                            <!--Email--> 
                            <td>@Html.LabelFor(p=>p.Email)<span style="color: #dc143c">*</span></td>
                            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(p=>p.Email, new {name = "txtEmail"})</td>
                        </tr>
                </table>

                <!--RIGHT SIDE-->
                <div>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(p => p.Password)</div>
                <table class="table-two">
                        <tr>
                            <!--Password-->
                            <td>@Html.LabelFor(p=>p.Password)<span style="color: #dc143c">*</span></td>
                            <td>@Html.PasswordFor(p=>p.Password, new {name = "txtPassword"})</td>
                        </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
         </fieldset>
   </div
```

**Before Validation**

[image]

**After Validation**

[image]

What could be the problem here? My idea is that the `float: right;` is the culprit, but I'm not familiar with another method to put the tables next to each other. Any ideas on what could be causing this shift?

Comment: It can be a lot of things. Maybe a JsFiddle or url would be nice. You can try to remove the empty line between the two tables.

Comment: Float both tables to the left

Comment: @Morpheus Same results.

Comment: @Dayan use developer tools to see if there is no margin or padding kicking in

Comment: @Sven Went ahead and added JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/YLQdy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `div` is a block element.

In your example you have

```
<div>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(p => p.Email)</div>
```

Which will take up the full width of the container.

Either put a `width` on the `div` such as

```
div.SomeClass{
   width: 50%;
   display: inline-block; // or use display to change how it is displayed
}
```

/ *** EDIT *** /

Wrap each section of `div` + `table` in a separate `div` that float respectively left and right. For example

```
<div class="left">
   //
</div>
<div class="right">
   //
</div>
```

and then use a `class="clearfix"` to the parent container to clear the floats.

```
.clearfix:after {
    content:" ";
    /* Older browser do not support empty content */
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
}
```

[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/YLQdy/3/)

Comment: @Dayan see my fiddle in the answer

Comment: I will try your new solution. But heads up, the Fiddle you included doesn't incorporate that fix :)

Comment: @Dayan, whoops bad copy pasta. Check now